# Pandas averaging duplicate pivot points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to heat map a data in the form of `X, Y, Z` where X and Y represents the X, Y coordinates and Z represents the power value at the point. I've put the data in the form of dataFrame by

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'X':X, 'Y':Y, 'Z':Z})
```

When I try the `data.pivot`, it will give me a duplicate entry error because there are points with same X and Y coordinates.

I was wondering if there are anyway to decimate the duplicates and average the Z value when there are duplicate X and Y value so they can be plotted as a seaborn heat map.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='X', columns='Y',values='Z',aggfunc=mean, fill_value=0)`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
X = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
Y = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
Z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

data = pd.DataFrame({'X':X, 'Y':Y, 'Z':Z})

data

   X  Y  Z
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  2  1  3
3  2  2  4
4  2  1  5
```

Use `groupby`

```
data.groupby(['X', 'Y'], as_index=False).mean()

   X  Y  Z
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  2  1  4
3  2  2  4
```